# Run Java Applet

Tags: firefox, java, 17.04, applet

I would like to use a JNLP file but it seems like I can't get Firefox (or Chrome) to use the Java Plugin (symbolic links to the libnpjp2.so file don't work).

So how can I use JNLP files?

**Update**
Java Version:

```
openjdk 9-Ubuntu
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-Ubuntu+0-9b161-1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-Ubuntu+0-9b161-1, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Have you installed Java support? Which one?

Comment: FF or Chrome don't support JAVA plugins any more.

Comment: Seems so - but what do I do now when I wanna use JNLP files?